# DataGridView Row is Bigger than DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm having an issue here where I have a DataGridViewRow that is bigger than the Height of the DataGridView and, while all the data is being loaded (I can copy it out) the vertical scroll bar is not there.

[image]

If I add an extra row I get the vertical scroll bar but it scrolls the the top of the large cell but you still can't see the bottom line.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ZKNhwAC.png]

Is there any way to make the DataGridView scroll through the rows instead of to the top of each one.

Comment: what you mean by "scroll through rows"?

Comment: I've removed the name and thanks from your question as it is irrelevant for the question. Refer [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Thanks Frebin. So it doesn't snap to the top of the next line, you can scroll to half way through the cell.